# easeljs beginBitmapFill method not working locally

Tags: easeljs

I just follow an example from this link "http://jsfiddle.net/RHbUw/75/" to test the beginBitmapFill method in Easeljs. This example works fine in jsfiddel environment via Firefox, IE and Chrome browsers.However, it doesn't work locally on my laptop no matter what browser I use. I've attached the exact same code from the jsfiddle link. Does anybody know the reason why this piece of code won't work locally?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.0.min.js ">
     </script>
     <script>
     var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
     var s = new createjs.Shape();
     stage.addChild(s);
     var img = new Image();
     img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png';
     s.graphics.beginBitmapFill(img, 'repeat-x');
     s.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1);
     s.graphics.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,0,0));
     s.graphics.drawRect(0,40,1000,1000);

     createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function() { stage.update(); });
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <canvas id="demoCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px #000 solid">
      </canvas>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second problem you have, try to put your code inside an img.onload function. This allows easeljs to draw your image only after the imagedata was available. Also you can use PreloadJS(that is also part of CreateJS) to load your images after your code begins.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
     s.graphics.beginBitmapFill(img, 'repeat-x');
     s.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1);
     s.graphics.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,0,0));
     s.graphics.drawRect(0,40,1000,1000);
}
img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png';
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been delivering the image as a dataurl, so it always came preloaded. But Safari *sometimes* didn't display it. Wrapping Easel initialization into the image load event resolved the issue. I'm also checking for `image.complete` and triggering the load event manually in case the image was cached.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I forgot to put the js code inside a function and call the function using onload inside the body tag. Sorry. However, there is still a littel problem with the code. The image won't show up when it is opened in IE. I have to hit the Enter so that the image will show up. If I click the refresh button, the image will disappear. It is same as in Chrome. It is odd!